# SQL select value from one column based on values in another column

Tags: sql, postgresql, join, where-clause

I have two tables. One stores "locations":

```
TABLE location (
    ID               serial             PRIMARY KEY,
    name             text               NOT NULL,
    description      text               NOT NULL
);
```

Each location has many rows of "data":

```
TABLE data(
    ID               smallint           REFERENCES location(ID),
    date             date,               
    rainfall         int                
);
```

I would like to find all locations that have "data" spanning a given period. I have tried this:

```
SELECT location.ID, location.name FROM location                    
    JOIN data ON data.id = location.id 
    WHERE (SELECT MIN(data.date) FROM data) <= '$start_date' 
           AND 
          (SELECT MAX(data.date) FROM data) >= '$end_date' 
    ORDER BY location.ID;
```

but it seems to apply the MIN and MAX test to all the data, not to each individual location i.e. the test needs to be applied to every location, and only return those locations that pass the test.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just aggregate by location and then assert the min/max from the `HAVING` clause:

```
SELECT
    l.ID,
    l.name
FROM location l                 
INNER JOIN data d
    ON d.id = l.id
GROUP BY
    l.ID
HAVING
    MIN(data.date) <= '$start_date' AND
    MAX(data.date) >= '$end_date' 
ORDER BY
    l.ID;
```

Answer (score 1):

When you say spanning a given period, why not use `between` like below

`SELECT location.ID, location.name FROM location location

    JOIN data d ON d.id = location.id 
    WHERE d.date between '$start_date'  AND  '$end_date' 
    ORDER BY location.ID;`

Note that both dates are inclusive here

Answer (score 0):

you could join a query result for those values and use that in the `where` condition

```
SELECT location.ID, location.name FROM location                    
JOIN data ON data.id = location.id 
JOIN (
    SELECT MIN(date) AS _min,MAX(date) AS _max,id
    FROM data
    GROUP BY id
) T ON T.id = location.id
WHERE T._min <= '$start_date' AND T._max >= '$end_date' 
ORDER BY location.ID;
```

just to clarify - I understood you want to get all the `data` for `locations` that have `data` in those time spans (the example implied this is what you wanted)

if you want to get all the `data` that "happened" in the time range this is not the solution for you, you want the `between` solution offered by @jusermar10 or @Yogs

Comment: Thanks - I actually wanted just the locations that have the required data.  The answer from @Tim Biegeleisen works for me.

Answer (score 0):

You could use between clause to get the desired results

```
SELECT l.ID, l.name FROM location l                   
    inner JOIN data d ON d.id = l.id 
    WHERE  d.date between '$start_date' and '$end_date' group by l.id
```

Answer (score 0):

When you say spanning a given period, I suppose you mean output only those locations that have all their `data.date` between `$start_date` and `$end_date`.

In that case this query should work:

```
SELECT location.ID, location.NAME FROM locations, data
WHERE locations.ID=data.ID
GROUP BY locations.ID
HAVING min(data.date) >= '$start_date' and max(data.date) <= $end_date;
```